# Como atualizar banco MySQL com Ajax + PHP

Tags: php, ajax

Preciso fazer uma atualização no meu banco de dados MySQL de forma assíncrona.

Tenho uma tabela com resultados do banco.

```
<?php 
        $sqlCategoria = "SELECT * FROM categorias";
        $resultCategoria = mysql_query($sqlCategoria);
        while($categorias = mysql_fetch_array($resultCategoria)){ 
?>
```

No while, coloquei esse script para fazer a atualização.

Porem só funciona a primeira vez.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function alterar_div() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "processo.php",
    data: {
        id_item: $('#id_item').val(),
        valor: $('#valor').val()
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('#conteudo').html(data);
    }
  });
}

</script>
```

Porque isso está acontecendo?

O Código como eu fiz!

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function alterar_div() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "processo.php",
    data: {
        id_item: $('#id_item').val(),
        valor: $('#valor').val()
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('#conteudo').html(data);
    }
  });
}
</script>

<?php 
    $sqlCategoria = "SELECT * FROM categorias";
    $resultCategoria = mysql_query($sqlCategoria);
    while($categorias = mysql_fetch_array($resultCategoria)){ 

        $sqlItens ="SELECT * FROM itens WHERE it_ctid = '".$categorias['ct_id']."'";
        $resultItens = mysql_query($sqlItens);
        while($itens = mysql_fetch_array($resultItens)){

            $sqlNao = "select rp_valor, rp_id from respostas
                            left join check_list on (ch_id = rp_chid)
                            left join itens on (it_id = rp_itid)
                            where ch_token = '".$token."' and it_id = '".$itens['it_id']."'";

            $resultNao = mysql_query($sqlNao);
            $valor = mysql_fetch_array($resultNao);

             }?>

    <input id="id_item" type="hidden" value="<? echo $valor['rp_id']; ?>" />
    <input id="valor" type="hidden" value="0" />
    <button type="button"  onclick="alterar_div()"> <img src="assets/imagens/bt_nao2.png" width="30" height="30" alt=""/></button>

<?php }?>
```

Arquivo processo.pho

```
<?php

include('includes/mysql.php');

$id = $_POST['id_item'];
$valor = $_POST['valor'];

$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE respostas SET rp_valor = '".$valor."' WHERE rp_id = '".$id."'");

?>
```

Comment: Você entende exatamente o que esse *script* faz?

Comment: Desculpa, tinha colocado o _script_ errado. Mais também não entendo muito não, se puder me ajudar! Não sei se entendeu o que eu preciso, hoje faço a atualização do meu banco via GET porem não posso recarregar a pagina para fazer essa atualização.

Comment: Tem como colocar o código completo?

Comment: Atualizei! Eu estava fazendo dessa forma `<a href="gravar/gravar_respostas.php?id=<? echo $itens['it_id']?>&valor=0&ch_id=<? echo $checklist['ch_id'];?>&token=<? echo $token;?>&id_lj=<? echo $id;?>&rp_id=<? echo $valor['rp_id']; ?>">` E assim vai!

Comment: Olá @AndersonCarlosWoss consegui me ajudar nessa? Obrigado